# How to find sum for each category in an array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, realm

I have an array that contains multiple items. This is a Realm array. It contains data in the following structure:

```
Results<Entry> <0x7ff04840e1a0> (
    [0] Entry {
        name = Salary;
        amount = 40000;
        date = 2020-03-18 16:00:00 +0000;
        category = Main Incomes;
        entryType = Income;
    },
    [1] Entry {
        name = Diff;
        amount = -500;
        date = 2020-04-18 16:00:00 +0000;
        category = Misc;
        entryType = Expense;
    },
    [2] Entry {
        name = Cat Food;
        amount = -399;
        date = 2020-04-18 16:00:00 +0000;
        category = Animals;
        entryType = Expense;
    },
    [3] Entry {
        name = Fish Food;
        amount = -599;
        date = 2020-04-18 16:00:00 +0000;
        category = Animals;
        entryType = Expense;
    }
)
```

What I am trying to achieve is to make another array that will 'pivot' totals for each category. So it can work as a pivot table in Excel.

The desired output is an array that will contain totals for each category:

```
[0] X-Array {
        category = Main Incomes;
        amount = XXXX;
    },
    [1] X-Array {
        category = Animals;
        amount = XXXX;

And so on...
```

I'm fairly new to this fancy one-liners like `.map` and `.reduce` and other Swift's array management sugar, so would very much appreciate the advice!

Thank you!

*P.S. I plan to do the same thing with total expenses and incomes in order to calculate closing balance.*

Comment: A quick look at the documentation shows that `Results` has some aggregation functions, why not use them? [Realm Aggregate Operations](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Results.html#/Aggregate%20Operations)

Comment: That's not an array, it's a Realm results object and while they are similar there are some distinct differences. Also, the question is a but unclear - Do you want the total of each entry type? e.g. Income = 4000, Expense = 500+399+599? Or are you looking for something else? Lastly, this isn't a code writing service - please show the code you've attempted and indicate what your stuck on. Please review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think use Dictionary is easier to do categorize and later you can convert it to array or anything you want

```
var dict:[String:Double] = [:]

list.forEach {
    if let current = dict[$0.category]{
        dict[$0.category] = current + $0.amount
    }else{
        dict[$0.category] = $0.amount
    }
}

print(dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is asking how to get the sum for each category, Income, Expense etc. If so, here's how it's done using the .sum function on the results.

```
let totalIncome = realm.objects(AccountClass.self)
                       .filter("entryType == 'Income'")
                       .sum(ofProperty: "amount") as Int
let totalExpense = realm.objects(AccountClass.self)
                        .filter("entryType == 'Expense'")
                        .sum(ofProperty: "amount") as Int

print("Total Income: \(totalIncome)")
print("Total Expense: \(totalExpense)")
```

and the output for your example data is

```
Total Income: 40000
Total Expense: 1498
```

If you want a pivot table, you could just add the amounts to an array - if you need the labels, use a tuple to store them in an array like this

```
let i = ("Income", totalIncome)
let e = ("Expense", totalExpense)

let tupleArray = [i, e]

for account in tupleArray {
   print(account.0, account.1)
}
```

Keep in mind that a Results object is not an array but has some array-like functions. Results are live updating so as the underlying data in Realm changes, the Results change along with it.