# Why headerView is always nil in numberOfRowsInSection?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have to make a dynamic datasource for a table, that satisfies the criteria:

- we do not know exact number of sections
- we do not know exact title for header in section
- we do not now how many rows it will be in each section each time

To detect number of rows per section I have the following code:

```swift
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        let header = tableView.headerView(forSection: section)
        return self.servicesData?.filter({ $0.clubName == header?.textLabel?.text }).count ?? 0
    }
```

where `servicesData` is the object array that is to be filtered by the header title aka `clubName`. Titles are gathered from the object array.

For some reason I always get `nil` when try to access the header. So far I tried calling `tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)` directly in `numberOfRowsInSection` but obviously with no luck.

Feedback much appreciated.

Comment: Obligatory, did you set the delegate?

Comment: @CSmizzle of course (if you mean `self.servicesTableView.delegate = self
        self.servicesTableView.dataSource = self`)

Comment: Do you calling `tableView.reloadData()` after you getting full list of `serviceData` ?

Comment: @Andrew yes, I call this method right after the fresh `serviceData` array is downloaded from the API

Comment: Can you post your cellForRowAt function?

Comment: @CSmizzle here: https://wtools.io/paste-code/b2Pl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is nil because it is not created at that moment. You should not use `tableView.headerView(forSection: section)` in `numberOfRows`. You should use the model from where you get the title to use it to filter in the array.

You should fetch all of your data before populating the table view and first. Then you should implement:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
   return headerModels.count
}
```

where headerModels it's an array of objects with your title and it's items like:

```
class HeaderModel {
   let title: String
   let items: [YourItem]
}
```

and then:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return headerModels[section].items.count
}
```

Comment: thank you! That solved the problem. Nevertheless while implementing your solution it came to mind that datasource can be passed in another way. I'll describe below.

Answer (score 1):

So, as per @shurtugal 's solution it is possible to pass-in an array of objects to populate the table. I thought that creating a utility class for this very case may be too much. So here's the slightly altered way:

Consider a dictionary `var servicesData = [String: [CustomObject]]()` that is populated each time the ViewController shows up. The dictionary can have indefinite number of keys and indefinite number of values inside each key. Algorithm of populating the dictionary is taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61303472/11841185) answer.

Thereby, `UITableViewDatasource` methods can be defined like this:

```swift
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        self.servicesData.count
    }
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return Array(self.servicesData.values)[section].count
    }
    
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        /* cell creation code code */
        
        /// sample line 
        cell?.someLabel.text = Array(self.servicesData.values)[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }
```